# C++ program to calculate e^x

Tags: c++, math

I  know there are many examples of this problem but I tried to write a different one myself.
This is using the Taylor series e^x = 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ......
My code compiles and runs but it wont output the correct answer for some imputes and I'm not sure why. is this even usable code or should i scrap it?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
   {
        double final,power,end_n = 1.0,e=1.0,x=2.0, n;
        cout<< "n: ";
       // usually enter 5 for test
        cin>> n;
        while (n>1){
            power = pow(x,n);
            end_n = end_n*n;
            e= (power/end_n)+e;
            n--;
        }
        final =e+x;
        cout<< final;
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How did you come up with that formulation for `end_n`?

Comment: Have you tried printing out intermediate values such as `power` and (especially) `end_n`?  Your loop is counting down `n`, but you have the loop body assuming that you are increasing `n` from `1` upwards.  Not surprisingly, this disconnect gives the wrong answers.  But printing values (or running the code in a debugger) is the best, simplest technique for finding out what's going on.

Comment: I think hobbs's answer nails it. Look also at Blindy's answer it does not answer your question but the code is what yours should be look like ... pow is overkill for integer exponents and can decrease precision not to mention performance. If you are doing many iterative computations it is a good idea to write some debug info like what you are dividing with what and the subresult per iteration that would clear things in seconds ... and also show if you are not overflowing/underflowing something or hit the rounding errors ...  some equations tent to do that very quickly

Answer (score 1):

I honestly have no idea what your reasoning is, at all. The code for that particular expansion is trivially simple:

```
double x;
cin >> x;

double oldres, res=1, top=1, bottom=1;
int iter=1;

do {
  oldres=res;                           // to calculate the difference between iterations

  ++iter;                               // next iteration
  top*=x;                               // multiply by one x for each iteration
  bottom*=(iter-1);                     // multiply by the iteration number for each iteration
  res+=top/bottom;                      // and add the fraction to the result
} while(fabs(res-oldres)>.1);           // while the difference is still large

cout << res;                            // done, show the result
```

Comment: I don't think this actually qualifies as an answer.

Comment: I think it does; it's a chance to see the code written properly.

Comment: Returns the absolute value of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To be very clear about something that others are hinting at: if your loop counted *up* from 1 to n then `end_n` would equal n! at each step. But counting down, it doesn't. Look at the examples from 1 to 5:

### Forwards

```
n | n!
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 6
4 | 24
5 | 120
```

### Backwards

```
n | end_n
5 | 5
4 | 20
3 | 60
2 | 120
1 | 120
```

Since absolutely none of your denominators are right, it's a surprise if your code is only wrong for *some* inputs — in fact it's probably only correct for x=0.

Finally, I hope that this is just an exercise for learning. If you really need the value of e^x you should use `exp(x)`.

Comment: so I pretty much did that part backwards?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close.  Maybe you want something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double factorial(long n)
{
    double result = n;
    while(--n) result*=n;
}

int main()
{
    long n, power;
    double final, e=1.0, x=2.0;
    cout<< "n: ";
    // usually enter 5 for test
    cin>> n;
    while (n>1)
    {
        power = pow((double)x, (double)n);
        end_n = factorial(n);
        e = (power/end_n)+e;
        n--;
    }
    final = e+x;
    cout<< final;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually employ a Horner-like scheme that uses the counting down in an essential manner

> 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + … + x^n/n! = (((((x/n+1)*x/(n-1)+1)*x/(n-2)+…)*x/1+1

```
    e = 1.0;
    while (n>0){
        e = e*x/n + 1;
        n--;
    }
```

Compare the approximations of `e^x` and `1/(e^-x)` for positive `x` for exactness.

Explore `(e^(x/4))^4` for better exactness.